# Auth0 Test Connection tries to log into wrong database

Tags: auth0

I have created a client and database and associated the two. When I create a user in this database, I am unable to log in using the test connection button.

When I check my logs, I don't see any attempt to log into this connection, rather I see a failed login for the connection Username-Password-Authentication. The connection I am testing is named bens-connection, this is just a standard auth0 database.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm which `Test Connection` button you are pressing. Is this `Connections -> Database -> bens-connection` then the `Try connection` tab?

- Is your Client definitely associated with the bens-connection database?
- Is your User definitely associated with the bens-connection database?

If so, then suggest you just copy out the URL when you hit the `Try connection` button and manually edit the connection name. Paste that into a URL and see if you can successfully login.

You should have a URL something like:

```
https://{{TENANT}}.auth0.com/login?client={{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}}&protocol=oauth2&redirect_uri=https://manage.auth0.com/tester/callback?connection=bens-connection&prompt=consent&response_type=code&connection=bens-connectionstate=sDZ8vs4tb2FqR3xnLpUnxIPhO7CiA5O4
```

You could also try the authorize endpoint using:

```
https://{{TENANT}}.auth0.com/authorize?client_id={{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}}&protocol=oauth2&connection=bens-connection&redirect_uri=https://jwt.io&response_type=token id_token&scope=openid email&nonce=123&state=xyz
```

Let me know how you get on, and I can update this answer based on further info.

Comment: In the end it was because the hosted login page for testing a client had been slightly modified.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.